# How do I add space between a video & a banner in the sidebar

Tags: html, iframe

I have in my sidebar a single video (embedded) and after that a few ads. I cant add a space between the video & the 1st ad even when writing the html code. any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your iframe in a div and use a margin to set a distance to the next element. Or give the iframe itself a margin.

Something like:

```
<div class="wrapperForIframe">
    <iframe>....content</iframe>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
div .wrapperForIframe {
        margin: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me please the code to put before & after my iFrame? I dont know html

Comment: I would then recommend having a look at www.w3schools.com/html.

To add a margin to your iframe wrap it in a div and use css to give it a margin